# Antonym for 'structure-dependent'

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

Not sure if this would be more suited to the linguistics site, but wondering what the antonym would be.

Example sentence would be:

> We find that grammars are consistently structure-dependent and not [word-here].

'Linear' or something might work but not sure what the technical term would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "syntactic" would be a single word for structure dependent, wrt linguistics: as in syntax as "The arrangement of words and phrases to create well-formed sentences in a language"

So either "non-syntactic" or "a-syntactic"?

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syntactic) :

> Syntactic : of, relating to, or according to the rules of syntax or syntactics

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asyntactic):

> Asyntactic :not syntactic, an asyntactic narrative